# SyntaxError: invalid syntax помогите плз не понимаю в чем проблема

Tags: python, python-3.x

Работаю с telebot, во всем коде было все нормально, но вылезла эта ошибка.

Сама строка:

```
 if message.text == ' Кубик':
            number = input('Введите число от 1 до 6:')
            if number == 6:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Кидаем кубик..." )
                random = (random.randint(1,6)
                if random != number:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы проиграли, выпало число " + str(number) + " чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start" )
                if random == number:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы выиграли! чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start")
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы ввели не правильное число!" )
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')
```

Ошибка:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (указывает на b в начале)
```

Comment: Конкатенация строк идет через знак плюс. То есть нужно писать вот так: `"Вы проиграли, выпало число" + str(number) + "чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start"`

Comment: если он показывает на букву b значит он не ожидает что там будет bot.send_message() значит ошибка выше ,может где пропустил скобку,покажи предыдущую строку. ну и то что ниже в ответах поправили тоже верно просто эти ошибки вылезли бы у тебя следующими

Comment: if random != number

Comment: там двуеточие :

Comment: у вас нет табуляции! это очень важно в пайтон

Comment: Скобку не закрыли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
random = (random.randint(1, 6))
```

вот тут ты забыл добавить скобку в конце

P.S вторая ошибка фиксится так , у тебя сьехал код иф должен быть на одном уровне с елс

```
if message.text == ' Кубик':
    number = input('Введите число от 1 до 6:')
    if number == 6:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Кидаем кубик..." )
        random = (random.randint(1,6))
        if random != number:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы проиграли, выпало число " + str(number) + " чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start" )
        if random == number:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы выиграли! чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы ввели не правильное число!" )
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')
```

Comment: теперь идет ошибка на двоеточие

Comment: покажи кусок кода полностью этот хандлер, по одной строке сложно понять в чем проблема,нажми на вопросе своем править и туда добавь код

Comment: if message.text == ' Кубик':
            number = input('Введите число от 1 до 6:')
            if number == 6:
             bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Кидаем кубик..." )
             random = (random.randint(1,6)
          if random != number:
          bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы проиграли, выпало число " + str(number) + " чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start" )
          if random == number:
          bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы выиграли! чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start")

Comment: все исправил ответ,пробуй

Comment: теперь IndentationError: expected an indented block ошибка

Comment: @Рамир это значит у тебя неправильные отступы нужно использовать клавишу tab

Comment: @Рамир дополнил ответ пробуй

Answer (score 2):

Вы не конкатенировали(сложили) строку, Вы просто написали через пробел ее куски

Попробуйте это:

```py
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы проиграли, выпало число"+str(number)+"чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start" )
```

Чтобы сложить строку нужно писать +:

```py
s = "a" "b" # ошибка
s = "a" + "b" # выходит "ab"
```

У Вас нет табуляции в этом фрагменте:

```py
if random != number:
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы проиграли, выпало число " + str(number) + " чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start" )
if random == number:
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы выиграли! чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start")
```

Должно быть так:

```py
if random != number:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы проиграли, выпало число " + str(number) + " чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start" )
if random == number:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы выиграли! чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start")
```

Comment: не сработало, та же ошибка

Comment: Можно точный текст ошибки?

Comment: В Python3 конструкция `s = "a" "b"` является синтаксически верной.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Может быть, тогда извиняюсь

Comment: @Рамир если какой-нибудь ответ вам помог, отметьте его как правильный пожалуйста и тем самым закройте вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Добавите `+` (дважды), т.е вместо

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы проиграли, выпало число" str(number) "чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start" )
```

напишите

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы проиграли, выпало число " + str(number) + " чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start" )
```

Comment: у меня ошибка именно в начале. Выдает на первую букву b

Comment: Можно точный текст ошибки?

Comment: bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы проиграли, выпало число " + str(number) + " чтобы вернуться назад напишите /start" )
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: @Рамир, я тестировал это, у меня всё в порядке. Значит, ошибка будет в предыдущей команде.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
random = (random.randint(1,6) 
if random != number:
```

напишите

```
random = random.randint(1,6) 
if random != number:
```

(без скобки после `=`).